# Django Unable to pass a variable name in the next template

Tags: django

Hi I am facing a problem in my project .

In the Patient list, if a Click the Notes row present in the Add notes column. The new template load  where it will list the recent notes for the patients... and also it allows me add patient notes  by selecting the patient ( i am passing the objects of patients through forms )

[image: view Patient]

[image: Add Notes]

My problem ..

How to add notes to the specified patient only. ( i.e. by not passing through forms)  and also filtering to display the specfic Patient notes only.

**Code**

```
Model:
class Notes(models.Model):
    doctorId = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    patientName = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    report = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    NoteDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    #def __str__(self):
     #   return self.patientName+" "+self.report
    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
```

**View**

```
@login_required(login_url='doctorlogin')
@user_passes_test(is_doctor)
def doctor_add_notes_view(request):
    appointmentForm=forms.PatientNotesForm()
    notes = models.Notes.objects.all().order_by('-NoteDate')
    mydict={'appointmentForm':appointmentForm,'notes':notes}
    if request.method=='POST':
        appointmentForm=forms.PatientNotesForm(request.POST)
        if appointmentForm.is_valid():
            appointment=appointmentForm.save(commit=False)
            appointment.doctorId =request.user.id #request.POST.get('doctorId')
            doctors = models.Appointment.objects.all().filter(AppointmentStatus=True, status=True)
            appointment.patientName = models.User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('patientId')).first_name
            now = datetime.now()
            print("Current date and time : ")
            print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            appointment.NoteDate = now
            print('doctors', doctors)
            appointment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('doctor-view-patient')
        else:
            print(appointmentForm.errors)
            return render(request, 'hospital/doctor_view_patient.html',{'alert_flag': True})
    return render(request,'hospital/doctor_add_notes.html',context=mydict)


def doctor_view_patient_view(request):

    appointments1 = models.Appointment.objects.all().filter(AppointmentStatus=False, status=True,doctorId=request.user.id)
    print('appointments are ', appointments1)
    patientid = []
    for a in appointments1:
        patientid.append(a.patientId)
        print('patientid', patientid)

    patients = models.Patient.objects.all().filter(PatientStatus=True, status=True, user_id__in=patientid)
    print('patients', patients)

    print(request.user.id)
    doctor=models.Doctor.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id) #for profile picture of doctor in sidebar
    print('doctor', doctor)

    notes = models.Notes.objects.all().order_by('-NoteDate')
    #print(notes)
    return render(request,'hospital/doctor_view_patient.html',{'patients':patients,'doctor':doctor,'notes':notes})
```

**Forms**

```
class PatientNotesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    patientId=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Patient.objects.all().filter(status=True),empty_label="Patient Name and Symptoms", to_field_name="user_id")
    class Meta:
        model=models.Notes
        fields=['report']
```

****doctor_view_patient.html**

```
{% extends 'hospital/doctor_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{%load static%}

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <style media="screen">
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    h6 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .row {
      margin: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title">Your Total Patient List</h6>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Profile Picture</th>
          <th>Symptoms</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        <th>Add Notes</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      {{Notes.get_id}}
      {% for p in patients %}
      <tr>
        <td> {{p.get_name}}</td>
        <td> <img src="{% static p.profile_pic.url %}" alt="Profile Pic" height="40px" width="40px" /></td>
        <td>{{p.symptoms}}</td>
        <td>{{p.mobile}}</td>
        <td>{{p.address}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url 'doctor-add-notes' %}">Notes</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**doctor_add_notes.html**

```
{% extends 'hospital/doctor_base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}

<head>
  <style media="screen">
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .note {
      text-align: center;
      height: 80px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0072ff, #8811c5);
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 80px;
    }

    .form-content {
      padding: 5%;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .form-control {
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
    }

    .btnSubmit {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
      padding: 1%;
      width: 20%;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #0062cc;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .menu {
      top: 50px;
    }
  </style>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<br><br>

<div class="container register-form">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="note">
        <p>Recent patient Notes</p>
      </div>

      </div>
      <table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{Notes.get_id}}
        {% for a in notes %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{a.patientName}}</td>
          <td>{{a.report}}</td>
          <td>{{a.NoteDate}}</td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="container register-form">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="note">
        <p>Add New Notes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              {% render_field appointmentForm.report class="form-control" placeholder="Description" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {% render_field appointmentForm.patientId class="form-control" placeholder="Patient" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {% render_field appointmentForm.NoteDate class="form-control" placeholder="Date" %}
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Can someone please help me as by clicking the Notes of a particular patient only specific to that user notes has to be displayed as well as to add notes to that patient only.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some R n D i was able to get through it just added a way to pass paramter as URL

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url 'doctor-add-notes' p.get_name %}">Notes</a></td>
```

and in Views

```
def doctor_add_notes_view(request,value):
    appointmentForm=forms.PatientNotesForm()
    print('value',value)
    #notes = models.Notes.objects.all().order_by('-NoteDate')
    notes = models.Notes.objects.all().filter(patientName=value).order_by('-NoteDate')
```

so URL becomes

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor-add-notes/P4**

this way i was able to solve the problem ( learnt a new thing )